# What sizes do I scale an image to in order to achieve resolution independance

Tags: android, graphics, vector-graphics

My app consists of a round ball whose radius I have specified as 35 pixels in the code. The user muse prevent the ball from colliding with other balls.

I have drawn an 800 px by 800 px vector graphic with 72 ppi resolution that I want to use as the bitmap for this image.

What sizes do I scale the image to for the drawable-ldpi, -mdpi and -hdpi folders so that the bitmap is the same size on all devices and also so that the collision detection works fine ? i.e. The app calculates the ball to be 35 pixels but the screen shows a smaller or larger image so the collisions will be all wrong and the user won't know what's going on.

I really don't know much about this so any help will be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

> To create alternative bitmap drawables for different densities, you
>   should follow the **3:4:6:8 scaling ratio** between the four generalized
>   densities. For example, if you have a bitmap drawable that's 48x48
>   pixels for medium-density screen (the size for a launcher icon), all
>   the different sizes should be:
>
> ```
> 36x36 for low-density
> 48x48 for medium-density
> 72x72 for high-density
> 96x96 for extra high-density
> ```

Also, one of the best practices for supporting multiple screen resolutions is: "Do not use hard-coded pixel values in your application code".

Since your applications deals with pixel values at runtime, you might want to read the section [Additional Density Considerations](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DensityConsiderations) and below that section.

Comment: That link was insightful but I have a couple of confusions. Suppose I provide only an hdpi image and none of the others. If the application is run on an mdpi device, the application will automatically scale the image down. Doesn't that mean that I don't have to do seperate scalings for each image? I think this would also consume less memory. Or is this done for best result and memory is a trade off?

Comment: And I just want to clarify that if I scale this image to hdpi proportions, will I still have to explicitly specify its density property using the BitmapFactory inDensity property ?

Comment: If you only provide a hdpi image and you run the app on a mdpi device, the application automatically scales down the images. Similarly, if you only have a mdpi image and run the app on a hdpi device, the app scales up the image. The scaling can cause artifacts in your images, so to ensure that your images look best, you SHOULD include alternative versions for different screen resolutions. Might save you some memory, but will definitely not give you the best results.
And I'm not sure about your question in your last comment...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Never mind the last question. I'd gotten a little confused but I managed to figure it out. Thanks :)